# Calculating the outer boundary of point clouds and export it as shapefile

Tags: python, point-cloud, concave-hull

I want to calculate the outer boundary of bunch of point clouds.
Going through different answers from stack I made this messy kind of solution, which works but is insanely slow. for 208 files(~117gb) it took almost 10 hours so this is definitely not a viable solution, even the manual work could be more faster.

Can someone guide me in improving this or choosing another faster approach, all I want is the outer boundary of the point clouds in .shp format.

```
import fiona
import timeit
import alphashape
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Polygon

directory = (r'somepath')

name_list = []
shape_list = []

for folder in Path(directory).glob('**'):
    for filename in folder.iterdir():
        if filename.suffix == '.txt':
            data = pd.read_csv(filename)
            gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data.X, data.Y), crs = 'EPSG:32610')
            alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(gdf['geometry'], 0)
            name_list.append(str(filename.stem))
            shape_list.append(alpha_shape)

final_data = list(zip(name_list,shape_list)) 
gdf_2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(final_data, columns = ['file_name', 'geometry'], geometry='geometry', crs = 'EPSG:32610')
gdf_2.to_file("somefile.shp")
```

Comment: Try PDAL with ´--boundary` https://pdal.io/en/stable/apps/info.html.

Comment: tested on one file, worked better in comparison to the alphashape. 
appreciate ur help